# Maximum likelihood estimation for trajectories estimation in python

Tags: python, prediction, mle

I am trying to predict trajectories using maximum likelihood estimation. How should I use the mean and variance from MLE to compute the parameters for my trajectory estimation?

Let's say I have a function representing the X coordinate of a gesture, where:
X(t)=a*X(t-1)+a1*X(t-2)+a2*Y(t-1)+ε and a2=da(2-1)+u, where ε and u are noise.
Where t represents the next time period, t-1 the current one and Y the Y coordinate of the hand. I need to estimate a, a1 and a1 using MLE in order to predict X(t).

Any suggestions since I am really new to this? 
Currently using some code in python for mean and variance computation.

```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np


  def expectation_max(data, max_iter=1000):
    data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    mu0 = data.mean()
    c0 = data.cov()

    for j in range(max_iter):
        w = []
        # perform the E part of algorithm
        for i in data:
            wk = (5 + len(data))/(5 + np.dot(np.dot(np.transpose(i - mu0), np.linalg.inv(c0)), (i - mu0)))
            w.append(wk)
            w = np.array(w)

        # perform the M part of the algorithm
        mu = (np.dot(w, data))/(np.sum(w))

        c = 0
        for i in range(len(data)):
            c += w[i] * np.dot((data[i] - mu0), (np.transpose(data[i] - mu0)))
        cov = c/len(data)

        mu0 = mu
        c0 = cov

    return mu0, c0
```

Comment: Do you have any data for us to play around with?

Comment: what do you mean by gesture and how is Y distributed?

Comment: @VersBersch by gesture I mean a series of x,y,z of a specific part of the hand and its evolution for a specific time t. In this case I have gaussian distribution, and thats why I have to choose MLE for the estimation.

Comment: This a looks like a problem for the Kalman Filter, which is a type of MLE update method.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter

Note that the Kalman filter is pretty challenging to understand and requires a background in control theory.

Here's a python implementation

https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1204/1204.0375.pdf

Comment: @mathew Gunther that's exactly my problem. I kind of understood how it works but it seems really difficult to me to implement it in the equation that I have.

Comment: I started writing an answer, but there's no math jax for stack overflow.  Will recommend this be moved to another subject domain that supports math jax.

Comment: @mathewgunther since I am still stuck, maybe I could use an answer here http://www.talkstats.com/threads/maximum-likelihood-estimation-for-trajectories-prediction.73843/?fbclid=IwAR1CfydhD5McT0vRF5zWMHjIllhfXTZW_FdCdzNQndka65lKuIj-04V0BC4

Comment: I flagged this for the moderator to move to another exchange that supports math jax, but that hasn't happened yet.  Ask the question on "cross validated", stat-exchange, or "computational science" and it will be quickly answered.

Comment: @mathewgunther i added it 4 days ago on cross validated and stat-exchange with no answer. Thanks anyway.